# Backup and restore database

Tags: mysql, windows, database

i am using mysql as my database server. I want to have a backup of database and restore them in case of machine crash. I am enetering the data through a GUI i Windows. I googled and read so much about automysqldump but i couldn't find the downloadable exe , i have downloaded the .sh file but i am very confused about how to use it. Please help me about this issue. I don't want to know how to use automysqldump but want to know any to backup and restore database using windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Make sure you can run `mysqldump` command in command prompt
2. make a `backup.bat` file, and write this command in that `mysqldump -u username -ppassword -h host databasename > C:\mybackupdata.sql` where `username` is your login-name for MySQL and `password` is the password that you use to login to MySQL. `host` will be `localhost` in your case.
3. Set it as scheduled task. It's very easy to do. See here http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308569

You may set it for daily for daily backup.

---

**Edit** Added more details as per comment

`mysqldump` is utility program gets installed when you install mysql server. You may try running this command on your console `mysqldump -u username -ppassword -h host databasename > C:\mybackupdata.sql` it should work.

I am assuming you have MySQL server installed on your machine and you can access your DB from command prompt using `mysql -u username -ppassword` if you get error like `command not found` most likely the path is not set. And you need to add mySQL's bin directory to your system path.

Comment: But where to find mysqldump and how to install it.

Comment: Please tell me how to install and get started.

Comment: On the windows server that has mysql installed, there should be a file somewhere called mysqldump.exe. Search for it.

Comment: Thanks Pelle but when i double click on it, just a window pops up and disappears. I triedto run it as administrator but got the same result.

Comment: @Suman.hassan95 dude, you need to 1. open command promp, 2. cd to the directory and 3. run `mysqldump -u username -ppassword -h host databasename > C:\mybackupdata.sql` command. And dont forget to replace **YOUR** actual username and password and host (maybe, localhost) in the command mentioned.

Comment: @Suman.hassan95 I have broken the answer in spoon-feeding steps. Can't help more.

Comment: @Suman.hassan95 if this answer helped you to solve the issue you may want to click `tick` mark it as correct answer and up-vote if you liked it.

Answer (score 0):

I personally use [Navicat](http://www.navicat.com/en/products/navicat_mysql/mysql_detail_win.html) to create scheduled backups. You can try the program for free for 30 days to see if it meets your needs.

[Here's a tutorial](http://www.navicat.com/manual/online_manual/en/win_manual/BackupRestore.html) on how to use the backup feature in navicat. It's super simple, set it and forget it.

fyi, I'm not affiliated w/ navicat in any way.

Comment: I have just tried Window's inbuilt Scheduled Task. It's pretty simple to use.

Comment: but when i click on backup it says to get a full version.

Answer (score 0):

I am using WAMP 2.2.  It is located here:

C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.5.20\bin